# Plotting time data as distance between 2 points in Excel

Tags: excel, plot, charts

Are there any wizards out there that can help me get a bit closer to the solution regarding this chart I'd like to do for a school project?
I have data regarding transport tasks and how long it took them. I would like to be able to plot them in a way that consecutively shows the length of each trip on the y axis while the x axis represents when the trip happened.
Example of data:

| Trip number | Trip Time | Trip Start | Trip Finish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06-09-2021 08:28:53 | 08:28:53 | 09:14:17 |
| 2 | 06-09-2021 09:00:00 | 09:00:00 | 10:21:18 |
| 3 | 07-09-2021 10:30:00 | 10:30:00 | 11:30:00 |

And I would like to chart it in a following way:

[image: Excel Chart]

Comment: sorry guys, something wrong with the table. I'm trying to edit it.

Comment: I think you want to use a stock market 'high-low-close' chart which Excel supports.  You might find it under "Chart Type..Waterfall".  You'll probably have to play around with it to suppress the close bar.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the layout of your data to this:

```
Trip No. Start/Finish
1        08:28:53
1        09:14:17
2        09:00:00
2        10:21:18
3        10:30:00
3        11:30:00
```

and then plot as a scatter with straight lines with markers chart, selecting each trip as a separate series. Adding each trip as a separate series means the lines should appear between each pair of points and each trip is a separate colour.

The Trip No. column is your x-axis data and the Start/Finish column is your y-axis data.

I have used the trip number rather than the Trip Time column as the x-axis to make the chart easier to read as time + date on the x axis tends to look a bit messy.

It should come out something like this:
[image: chart]

Comment: Hey, I have tried it. I get decent results, but the actual data has 110 data points. I'm having a bit of difficulty finding out how to select each trip as a separate series. Can you help?

Comment: @Adrian you'll need to use the 'Select Data' option in the Chart Tools -> Design tab when you have the chart select. In this window you can 'add' each series manually, selecting the x and y values from your sheet. However, this will take some time with 110 series and I think you are hitting up against the limitations of Excel with this many series that require manual selection. If you wanted to automate this process you'll need to take the data into another program, such as R, and create the chart in there.

Comment: Not to say that you can't create the chart in Excel, just that it will be a bit finicky and take some time to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your time here. I used perhaps 6 hours between today and yesterday on this and I'm not seeming to make much progress. It's a time like this when I wish I was better at Excel. I looked into this R language and it's really impressive. It's probably not a bad idea to learn it when I'm finished with school. Would it be possible that maybe I share the data with you and the type of charts I'd like to have and maybe you could help me make them and I could pay you some money? It'd probably take me days to do that while I'd imagine not much time for someone that knows the programs.